# What are Silver Pantaloons for?

Tags: baldurs-gate-2

In Baldur's Gate 2, I got the item `Silver Pantaloons`.

What is the purpose of this item? Is it useful or can I toss it?

Comment: Now I need to go play BG2 again... *Go for the eyes Boo, go for the eyes! YARRGH!!*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Silver Pantaloons are part of a bonus item set you can get by playing the same character through Baldur's Gate 1, 2 and ToB.

If you collect these items while playing:

- [The Golden Pantaloons](http://www.planetbaldursgate.com/bg2/walkthrough/bmu/golden_pantaloons.shtml) from BG1
- [The Silver Pantaloons](http://www.planetbaldursgate.com/bg2/walkthrough/bmu/silver_pantaloons.shtml) from BG2
- [The Bronze Pantalettes](http://www.planetbaldursgate.com/bg2/walkthrough/bmu/bronze_pantalettes.shtml) from ToB

After getting all three, you can have Kerrick the Smith in Amkethran combine them into the [Big Metal Unit](http://www.planetbaldursgate.com/bg2/walkthrough/bmu/building_bmu.shtml): a -10AC armor suit that anyone can wear, as well as a Big Metal Rod that can shoot 3 different kinds of ammo.

Source: [Big Metal Unit guide](http://www.planetbaldursgate.com/bg2/walkthrough/bmu/)

There's also a rambling history on the subject [at baldurdash.org](http://www.baldurdash.org/pantaloons.html)

Comment: +1: I just picked up the golden pantaloons from BG1 the other day. Now I just have to play it all the way through again.

Answer (score 1):

[Here you go](http://www.gamebanshee.com/baldursgateii/pantaloonsenigma.php):

Returning to Kerrick the Smith in Amkethran, he would then forge the Golden Pantaloons, the Silver Pantaloons, and the Bronze Pantalettes, for no charge in gold whatsoever, into:

- The Big Metal Unit: A suit of armour, wearable by all characters, with a base Armour Class of -10, that gives the player the size and appearance of an Iron or Adamantite Golem.
- The Big Metal Rod: A launcher for several types of ammunition.
- Scorcher, Pulse and Frag Grenade ammunition for the Big Metal Rod.